# KQL query string parameter default value

Tags: search, content, kql, default

I have to filter my search result WP using a query string parameter in the KQL query:

```
myfield:{QueryString.XXXX}.
```

I need to be able to define a default filtering or default value for `myfield` if the query string parameter is empty.

How could achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ? operator. For example: `{?myfield:{QueryString:XXXX}}` will not effect the outcome of the query if the field has no value. You may have to play with it a bit but all the details are well documented and explained by Mikael: https://www.itunity.com/article/sharepoint-query-variables-295